# Setting Alpha Value to Zero in IPhone Interface Builder Renders Button Unclickable

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, interface-builder, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make a button that is invisible but that can still be clicked. Setting the 'Hidden' property to true makes it non-clickable as does setting the alpha value to zero. Setting the alpha to .02 makes the button work, but also makes it slightly visible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the button type to Custom, this will hide the default style of the button

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple to do. Just forget about alpha parameter and use Custom instead of RoundedRect  in the Button Attributes->Type.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to custom or 0.01, custom makes it not visible, you could also set the alpha programatically to 0.0000000000000000000001 like this, [//outlet setAlpha://ur number];